# MVC Web API Exception Handler JSON Debug Info with OWIN/Kotana

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

This is going to sound odd perhaps, but I am trying to figure out WHERE debug information about exceptions is being transmitted from within an MVC Web API. Whenever an exception occurs, it returns an object (JSON formatted because I removed the XML formatter) with the following attributes:

- Message
- ExceptionMessage
- ExceptionType
- StackTrace

I replaced the existing implementation of IExceptionHandler with the following line in `WebApiConfig.Register()`

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new CustomExceptionHandler());
```

However, even though I'm able to confirm that the new handler IS being called when an exception occurs (via debug breakpoints), the same JSON object with debug information about the error gets returned.

My question is this: What stock system or mechanism is responsible for generating and sending this information?